# How does calling a program in Windows XP from "Run..." with a colon argument work?

Tags: windows, syntax, command-line

I noticed that a certain program works in a special way when sending an argument.

The only way to send an argument is by clicking "Start -> Run..." and typing:

```
[programname]:[argument]
```

for e.g (which does not work anyway)

```
notepad:textfile.txt
```

If I try to do the same from a Command-line-window, it doesn't work. Neither does "programname argument". I must be able to open the program with an argument from a website (with Wscript shell which is another story) but this will probably not work.

Does anyone have a clue how this strange colon syntax works?

UPDATE:
As requested, here's a real example:

```
AGS:pref.serv01.com(ARG1:ARG2)
```

That's the exact syntax, which results in the program opening the specific information for ARG1 and ARG2. AGS is just the name of the program which is a normal windows-program.

Comment: Could you give us a real example.

Comment: What is AGS? ....

Comment: I suspect `AGS` is a protocol like `http`. If so, the way to "run" a url from cmd.exe is to specify a program and pass the url to it, such as `genericbrowser.exe http://www.foobar.com` What program handles the `AGS` protocol?

Comment: @Mike: If you want to post comments, first create a full account on Stack Overflow, then log in with it here.

Comment: @horatio: No, the closest to the *Run* dialog would be to use `start`.

Answer (score 1):

The *Run...* dialog is not limited to local files – it also accepts all URI schemes<sup>1</sup> [registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the system For example, you can open `http:` or `ftp:` addresses in it. It's possible that some program simply registered the `AGS:` URI scheme for this purpose. (The entire URI is passed unmodified to the program, which can apply its own parsing rules.)

Take a look at the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AGS` key in the Registry Editor and see if it says anything about your program, whether it has a value named "`URL Protocol`" in it, and what does the `shell\open\command` subkey point at.

---

<sup>1</sup> Windows calls them "URL protocols", which is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

The colon character is used to refer to [Alternate Data Streams](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763) in NTFS. Maybe your program has hidden data streams with executables in it.

I think that it cannot be done from the command line argument, because the shell parser gets confused. The "run" dialog however is much more permissive.

If it is so, you can try to extract it by simply:

```
c:> type program:argument > output
```

Comment: This is a possibility, but in this case the streams would be named like `:pref.serv01.com(ARG1:ARG2)`, and I find it unlikely that there would be a separate stream, containing a full executable in each, named after every possible server/arg1/arg2 combination.

Comment: In addition, `:pref.serv01.com(ARG1:ARG2)` is not even a valid stream name, since the `ARG2)` part would be interpreted as *stream type* and all [valid types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) start with `$`.